# Strange error on `typedef struct` in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, struct, typedef

I'm trying to compile a plain C program in MSVC 6.0 that has the following:

```
typedef struct _unitID {
    int sock;           // socket
    unsigned long au;    // the AU ID
} unitID;
```

However, the compiler raises a strange error:

```
error C 2085: 'unitID' not in formal parameter list
```

I'm not sure that I understand what the compiler is complaining about, since according to [microsoft's own page on the error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229473%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) this means *"The identifier was declared in a function definition but not in the formal parameter list."*

Considering that the above snippet constitutes the entire header, and that **there are no function in the file**, how can I get this to compile successfully?

**[EDIT - RESOLVED]:** Due to a cascading error from a typedef declared in the including file prior to this.

Comment: Are you including anything before this ?

Comment: sure: either `<stdio.h>` or `<glib.h>` and that's it.

Comment: There is no problem with the snippet you have provided

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, I know. Tell that to the compiler.

Comment: @brice it compiles fine for me

Comment: Since you generally don't compile a header file on its own, what does the file that includes it, that you're actually compiling, look like?

Comment: @All: It's due to a previous typedef causing a cascading error. @Rahul - you're absolutely right.

Comment: You should answer your own question so that the question is marked resolved.  It also helps in case someone else has the same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem:

The Problem is caused by a typedef declared in the including file:

File [main.c]:

```
#include <glib.h>
//...
#if (!GLIB_CHECK_VERSION(2,11,0))
typedef pid_t GPid;
#endif
//...
#include "someheader.h"
//...
```

File [someheader.h]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unitid.h"
//...
```

File [unitid.h]:

```
typedef struct _unitID {
    int sock;           // socket
    unsigned long au;    // the AU ID
} unitID;
```

The error with the first typedef cascades all the way into unitid.h, causing the strange behaviour. Because we're building with an older version of Glib, the typedef causes an error.

#### Solution

The solution was to add a platform check to handle the difference in how the two platforms deal with PIDs as can be seen in [main.c]:

```
//...
#if (!GLIB_CHECK_VERSION(2,11,0))
#ifdef WIN32
  typedef void* GPid;
#else
  typedef int GPId;
#endif
#endif
//...
```